# Date filtering not working in react-table column filter

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I have created a table with react-table and I am having a column filter for each column. In a few columns, I have date and when I am trying to filter date it's not working. Any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Date filter started working once I changed the date format coming from database.